# How do I prove that a reduced density matrix has properties of a density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, trace

The properties of a density matrix are defined as follows:

$(1) \ \ \mathrm{Tr}\rho = 1 $

$(2) \ \ \rho^\dagger = \rho $

$(3) \ \ \rho \ge 0 $

$(4) \ \ \mathrm{Tr}\rho^2 \le 1 $

A reduced density matrix of a subsystem $A$ is defined as $\rho_A  = \mathrm{Tr}_B \rho$ where $ \mathrm{Tr}_B(\cdot)$  is the partial trace over subsystem $B$.

It is pretty straightforward to show that properties $(1)-(3)$ are true for the reduced density matrix $\rho_A$ but I can't find any proof of $(4)$ nor can I do it myself (it's easy only in case where $\rho$ is diagonal). Has anyone come across anything that would be somewhat helpful in proving the last property for the reduced density matrix?

Comment: See "Quantum Computation and Information" by Nielsen and Chuang, Section 2.4.3, especially Box 2.6

Comment: In finite dimensions, a density operator is by definition a positive operator of unit trace. Properties $(2)$ and $(4)$ follow from that. Anyway, if you have shown that a spectral decomposition exists, why you won't use it to show $(4)$?!

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose $Tr(\rho_{A}^{2})>1$, then $Tr(\rho^{2}) \leq 1$ is impossible since all diagonal components of $\rho^{2}$ is positive in eigenbasis of $\rho$.